# Run ScadaLTS with derby

Tags: derby, scadalts

Is it possible to run ScadaLTS with derby instead mysql?
I tried to change to env.properties file but Scada doesn't srtart.

Thanks.

Comment: Even if it starts, it will not work everything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I'm using the ScadaLTS with Derby.
edit the env.properties file. You can find how change the env.properties file from ScadaBR manual Chapter 8

You can find a copy here:
 [Manual ScadaBR English 8 Chapter 8](https://sourceforge.net/p/scadabr/wiki/Manual%20ScadaBR%20English%208%20Chapter%208/)

Feedback are welcome!